# Obtaining config values from within non-spring managed bean

Tags: java, spring

I'm using annotation-configuration, not XML for my application...

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.production"
    })
@PropertySource(value= {
        "classpath:/application.properties",
        "classpath:/environment-${COMPANY_ENVIRONMENT}.properties"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.production.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
public class Config {
    @Value("${db.url}")
    String PROPERTY_DATABASE_URL;
    @Value("${db.user}")
    String PROPERTY_DATABASE_USER;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    String PROPERTY_DATABASE_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${persistenceUnit.default}")
    String PROPERTY_DEFAULT_PERSISTENCE_UNIT;
```

In this file I've noticed I can obtain configuration values from the `@PropertySource` files.  How can I obtain these values outside of a spring managed bean?

Is it possible for me to use my `ApplicationContextProvider` to obtain these values?

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext (ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, yes you can use your `ApplicationContextProvider` class. `@PropertySource` properties end up in the `ApplicationContext` `Environment`. You can therefore access them like

```
public static class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext (ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        Environment env = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("db.user")); // access them 
    }
}
```

So basically anywhere you have a reference to the `ApplicationContext`, you can get the properties declared in a `@PropertySources` or a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

However, in this case, the `ApplicationContextProvider` will have to be declared as a Spring bean in your context.

```
@Bean
public ApplicationContextProvider contextProvider() {
    return new ApplicationContextProvider();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Why does it have to be defined as a Spring bean?  Within my app I'm always using this statically.

Comment: @Webnet It doesn't _really_ have to, but if it is, Spring will take care of calling and setting the `ApplicationContext`. Otherwise, you will need to call it yourself once you're done initializing it.